# Applicative functors. Type signatures of <*> and <$> in detail

Tags: haskell, applicative

We have signatures:

```hs
(<$>) :: Functor f     =>   (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Let us play with it a bit:

```hs
(/)  <$> Just 5       <*> Just 2
=> Just 2.5

((/) <$> Just 5     ) <*> Just 2
=> Just 2.5

( Just (\x -> 5/x ) ) <*> Just 2
=> Just 2.5
```

**Question:**

```
((/) <$> Just 5) <*> Just 2
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     @@@@@@

(<$>) :: Functor f     =>   (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
                                               ^^^
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
                          ^^^^^^^^^^    @@@
```

I interpret that ^^^ parts should match by their type. How come return type of `<$>` doesn't visually match input type of `<*>` in signatures?

What do I miss here? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: start by writing out the type of `(/)` and deciding what `a` and `b` are. Remember that functions are curried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does match, but the `f`, `a` and `b` of the `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` function are variables, and the variables are different variables each time you use that function.

It therefore makes more sense to define the functions here as:

```
(<$>) :: Functor f     => (a -> b)   -> f a -> f b
(<*>) :: Applicative g => g (c -> d) -> g c -> g d
```

So that means that the `^` and `@` indeed match like:

```
((/) <$> Just 5) <*> Just 2
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     @@@@@@

(<$>) :: Functor f     => (a -> b)   -> f a -> f b
                                               ^^^
(<*>) :: Applicative g => g (c -> d) -> g c -> g d
                          ^^^^^^^^^^    @@@
```

So we know that the type of `(/) <$> Just 5` is `f b`, and `g (c -> d)`, whereas `Just 2` has type `g c`. Since `Just 2` has type `Just 2 :: Num n => Maybe n`, that thus means that `g ~ Maybe` and `c ~ n` (here `x ~ y` means `x` and `y` are the same type). Furthermore we can derive that `f b ~ g (c -> d)`, so `f ~ Maybe`, and `b ~ (c -> d)`.

We can furthermore analyze the `(/) <$> Just 5` expression. We know that `Just 5` has type `Num m => Maybe m`, so that means that `a ~ m`. The function `(/)` has type `(/) :: Fractional k => k -> k -> k`, so that means that `a ~ b ~ k ~ m`, and therefore we know that `(/) <$> Just 5` has type `(/) <$> Just 5 :: (Num m, Fractional m) => Maybe (m -> m)`, or less verbose `(/) <$> Just 5 :: Fractional m => Maybe (m -> m)` (a `Fractional m` implies `Num m`).

As we already found out `b ~ (c -> d)`, so that means that `m ~ c ~ d`, and thus the type of the expression is: `((/) <$> Just 5) <*> Just 2 :: Fractional m => Maybe m`.

Comment: thanks. seems you need to make a little correction at: ...and therefore we know that `(/) <$> Just 5 has type (/) <$> Just 5 :: (Num m, Fractional m) => Maybe (m -> m)`

Comment: Could you give me more hints on Applicative? I see similarity between usual multiparameter fn application `f x y z` and applicative `f <$> x <*> y <*> z`, however I can't imagine any direct analogues of <*> and <$> in usual fn application world? Also I feel partial application is somehow involved here?

Comment: `(/) <$> Just 5`, will result in `Just ((/) 5)`, so yes you are correct taht partial application is involved here. `Just ((/) 5) <*> Just 2`, then thus results in `Just ((/) 5 2)`, and thus `Just 2.5`.

Comment: Yet somehow to calculate `f x y z` we don't define any new functions (like we do with <*> and <$>... I still miss some element here...

Comment: What do you mean with "we don't define any new functions"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199123/discussion-between-max-and-willem-van-onsem).